# WPF VB App no longer loading Application scope applicationSettings

Tags: wpf, vb.net, exe.config

I have a few VB.net WPF applications with a combination of settings using the later applicationSettings and earlier appSettings all in the application.exe.config files.

I have just noticed that for the last few months re-compiled applications are not reading the applicationSettings from the application.exe.config file but are instead just using the default values configured within the Visual Studio project.

I've also had a few problems with Visual Studio updates corrupting the Settings.Designer.vb file. This seems to be somewhere between VS versions 17.2 and 17.9. This has usually been solved by removing the top My namespace or adding the My namespace into other parts of the application that are trying to use it - this has mostly been older legacy references. I suspect there may be a connection.

I have spent most of today trying to get the app to read the settings from the app.exe.config without any success. So I've had to resort to a hack to read the settings xml file manually and then apply the settings from there. For reference my code for this is below - sorry the XML is a little sloppy. If anyone knows what the cause/solution is please let us know.

```
Private Shared Sub InitialiseSettings()
    appSettings = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim appConfigExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location() & ".Config"
    If IO.File.Exists(appConfigExe) Then
        Try
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument
            doc.Load(appConfigExe)
            Dim applicationSettings = doc.GetElementsByTagName("applicationSettings")
            Dim xmlSettings As XmlNode = applicationSettings(0)
            For Each allSettings As XmlNode In xmlSettings
                For Each ndSetting As XmlNode In allSettings.ChildNodes
                    Try
                        If ndSetting.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim at As Xml.XmlAttribute = ndSetting.Attributes("name")
                            If at IsNot Nothing AndAlso at.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                                Dim name = at.Value
                                For Each ndValue As XmlNode In ndSetting.ChildNodes
                                    Dim value = ndValue.InnerText
                                    If Not appSettings.ContainsKey(name) Then
                                        appSettings.Add(name, value)
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                Next
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
Private Shared appSettings As Dictionary(Of String, String)
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Settings(key As String) As String
    Get
        If appSettings.ContainsKey(key) Then Return appSettings(key)
        Return ""
    End Get
End Property
```

This can be called with something like this:

```
Dim var = Settings("MySettingName")
```